# Error when running ip_loadbalancer app of pox

Tags: python, mininet, pox

I have this topology
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSController
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost, Host, Node
from mininet.node import OVSKernelSwitch, UserSwitch
from mininet.node import IVSSwitch
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.link import Intf
from subprocess import call

def myNetwork():

  net = Mininet( topo=None, build=False, link=TCLink, 
  controller=RemoteController)

  linkopts = dict(bw=100, delay='1us', loss=0)
  info( '*** Adding controller\n' )
  controller1=net.addController(name='controller1', 
  controller=RemoteController, protocol='tcp', port=6633)
  controller2=net.addController( name='controller2', 
  controller=RemoteController, protocol='tcp', port=6644)


  info( '*** Add switches\n')

  switch1 = net.addSwitch('switch1', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
  switch2 = net.addSwitch('switch2', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
  net.addLink(switch1, switch2, **linkopts)

  controller1.start( )
  switch1.start([controller1])
  controller2.start( )
  switch2.start([controller2])

  #switch1.cmd ('ovs-vsctl set Bridge switch1 protocols=OpenFlow10')
  #switch2.cmd ('ovs-vsctl set Bridge switch2 protocols=OpenFlow10')

  server1 = net.addHost('server1', cls=Node, ip='10.0.0.1')
  net.addLink(switch1, server1, **linkopts)

  server2 = net.addHost('server2', cls=Node, ip='10.0.0.2')
  net.addLink(switch2, server2, **linkopts)
  service = net.addHost('service', cls=Node, ip='10.0.0.3')
  net.addLink(switch2, service, **linkopts)

  info( '*** Add hosts\n')
  for h in range(0,32):
         client = net.addHost('client%s' % (h + 1))
         net.addLink(client, switch1, **linkopts)

  for h in range(32,64):
         client = net.addHost('client%s' % (h + 1))
         net.addLink(client, switch2, **linkopts)



  info( '*** Starting network\n')
  net.build()
  net.start()

  CLI(net)
  net.stop()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
     setLogLevel( 'info' )
     myNetwork()
```

and I want to run ip_loadbalancer application from pox controller with two instances to run two controllers. when we run it, it gives this list of errors.

```
ERROR:core:Exception while handling OpenFlowNexus!PacketIn...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/eman/pox/pox/lib/revent/revent.py", line 231, in 
raiseEventNoErrors
return self.raiseEvent(event, *args, **kw)
File "/home/eman/pox/pox/lib/revent/revent.py", line 278, in 
raiseEvent
rv = event._invoke(handler, *args, **kw)
File "/home/eman/pox/pox/lib/revent/revent.py", line 156, in _invoke
return handler(self, *args, **kw)
File "/home/eman/pox/pox/proto/arp_responder.py", line 189, in 
_handle_PacketIn
if _arp_table[a.protosrc] != a.hwsrc:
File "/home/eman/pox/pox/proto/arp_responder.py", line 78, in __ne__
return not self.__eq__(other)
File "/home/eman/pox/pox/proto/arp_responder.py", line 76, in __eq__
return self.mac == other
File "/home/eman/pox/pox/lib/addresses.py", line 214, in __cmp__
return -other.__cmp__(self)
TypeError: bool.__cmp__(x,y) requires y to be a 'bool', not a 
'EthAddr'
```

what can I do to remove this error?

Comment: if you remove the for loop where you add hosts , the 7 lines after `info( '*** Add hosts\n')` does it work?

Comment: No it gives the same error @SotirisTsartsaris